# Is there a analogue of Matlab's `bsxfun` for matrix multiplication/division?

Tags: matlab, vectorization, bsxfun

I need to multiply a list vectors by a list of matrices. Currently I am doing it with a for loop:

```
for k=1:N
    x(:,k)= A(:,:,k) \ b(:,k);
end
```

Can I write this without the `for` loop?

Comment: Sometimes a loop is all you need ...

Comment: fine by me, if that's the thing to do.

Comment: oufcourse I could create a huge sparse matrix and solve that...

Answer (score 1):

If you're really looking for a solution (which might be slower ; you need to profile), I'd store my matrices in a cell array (such that `A(:,:,k) = A{k}`). Then:

```
x = reshape(  blkdiag(A{:})\b(:)   ,   numel(b)/N,   N  );
```